# Align multiple images of different size in \titlegraphic inside Beamer

Tags: beamer, horizontal-alignment

I want to use few logo in title page inside Beamer. The logo images are different sizes making them difficult to align properly. Below is the code:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{beamer}
\usetheme{Madrid}
\usecolortheme{seahorse}
\usefonttheme{serif}

\title[Short title]{Really really really really Long title\\takes around two lines}
\author{Author Name}
\institute[]{Institute name goes here}

\date{\today}

\titlegraphic{\includegraphics[height=1.5cm]{small_logo_1}\hspace*{1cm}\includegraphics[height=1.5cm]{small_logo_2}\hspace*{1cm}\includegraphics[height=1.5cm]{big_logo_1}}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[noframenumbering]
    \titlepage
\end{frame}   
\end{document}
```

Below is the generated slide:

[image]

I want to align these logos in such a way that the middle one comes in the center of the page and the other two stay equally far from the middle logo.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can calculate the adjustment you need from the widths of the left and right images. For example,

```
\documentclass[11pt]{beamer}
\usetheme{Madrid}
\usecolortheme{seahorse}
\usefonttheme{serif}
\title[Short title]{Really really really really Long title\\takes around two lines}
\author{Author Name}
\institute[]{Institute name goes here}
\date{\today}
\usepackage{calc}
\newlength\logoawidth
\newlength\logobwidth
\newlength\logoadjwidth
\settowidth\logoawidth{\includegraphics[height=1.5cm]{example-image-a}}
\settowidth\logobwidth{\includegraphics[height=1.5cm]{example-image-a4}}
\setlength\logoadjwidth{.5\logobwidth-.5\logoawidth}

\titlegraphic{%
    \hspace*{\logoadjwidth}%
    \includegraphics[height=1.5cm]{example-image-a}\hspace*{1cm}\includegraphics[height=1.5cm]{example-image-b}\hspace*{1cm}\includegraphics[height=1.5cm]{example-image-a4}%
}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[noframenumbering]
    \titlepage
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image: centred centre]

This moves the centre image left because the left image is wider than the right. In your case, it would move it right because the right image is wider than the left. (I had to change the images, obviously, since I don't have your files.)

Comment: Yeah... This is what I was looking for! Thanks a lot buddy.